# Angular JS: Bind textarea content to specific array of objects

Tags: angularjs, textarea, angularjs-ng-model, angular-nglist

Is there any simple (or no so simple) way to bind textarea model to specific array of objects?

Textarea

[image]

By now I am able to bind it to simple array using some specific symbol in ng-list directive:

```
<textarea ng-trim="false" ng-list="&#10;"></textarea>
```

This gives me an array like this:

```
["value1;value2;value3;", "value1;value2;value3;", "value1;value2;value3;"]
```

However, I want to achieve this:

```
[{field1: "value1", field2: "value2", field3: "value3"}, {field1: "value1", field2: "value2", field3: "value3"}]
```

Comment: It is always helpful to create a simple fiddle to illustrate your issue and for others to help you. I created one here: https://jsfiddle.net/frishi/1sxh076m/
Are you trying to bind the textarea to a specific object in your array? What you are trying to achieve is quite unclear.

Answer (score 0):

You can build a function like this:

```
$scope.createObject = function(){
  $scope.newAr = []

  for(var i = 0; i < $scope.data.length; i++){
    var str = $scope.data[i]

    var splitStr = str.split(";");
    var obj = {};

    for(var j = 0; j < splitStr.length; j++){
      obj['field'+(j+1)] = splitStr[j];
    }
    $scope.newAr.push(obj)
  }
}
```

Then call it with ng-change like:

```
<textarea ng-change="createObject()" ng-model="data" ng-trim="false" ng-list="&#10;"></textarea>
```

[Here](https://plnkr.co/edit/k9rtVKQVpHXum8SsrBAp) is a working plunker.

Comment: Yes, I tried something like this before. But there is no validation behind, because the input has to be exactly in form value1:value2;value3, that means two semicolons for three values on each line.

Comment: OK so what are you looking for?? I only gave an example of the exact functionality that you asked for in the question.